# Remove just one event handler using jquery ".off"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I borrowed this code from somewhere to switch from one bootstrap modal to another. After the switch, I want to turn off the handler so it doesn't switch every time I simply close the first modal. My problem is that once the modal switching function is used, I don't know how to turn **only** that specific event handler off without turning off the other event I have firing when a certain modal closes (done elsewhere). Any suggestions?

```
//switch modals
function switchModals(fromModal, toModal) {
    $(fromModal).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $(toModal).modal('show');
        //clear this function so it doesn't show up if they exit the window again
        $(fromModal).off('hidden.bs.modal');
    });
    $(fromModal).modal('hide');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I just had to give the handler a namespace that's unique to the function. Then I unbound it by its namespace in the ".off()" method. I chose "switch" as the namespace.

```
//switch modals
function switchModals(fromModal, toModal) {
    $(fromModal).on('hidden.bs.modal.switch', function (e) {
        $(toModal).modal('show');
        //clear this function so it doesn't show up if they exit the window again
        $(fromModal).off('.switch');
    });
    $(fromModal).modal('hide');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put this line outside the switchModals

```
$(<FromModalId>).modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `this` instead of `fromModal` inside the `hidden.bs.modal` callback, e.g.

```
//switch modals
function switchModals(fromModal, toModal) {
    $(fromModal).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $(toModal).modal('show');
        //clear this function so it doesn't show up if they exit the window again
        $(this).off('hidden.bs.modal');
    });
    $(fromModal).modal('hide');
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. I think it needs to be specified somewhere in the .off(), but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: Can you post your full code, or a link to to your web page?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to toggle between modals:

```
    var el = fromModal+','+toModal;
    $(el).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $(el).not(this).modal('show');
        $(this).modal('hide');
    });
```